# How to set maxdate and mindate in uib-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Below is my Controller and html code where I'm implementing date and can someone explain me how to add maxdate and mindate to below code.

```js
app.controller('viewfullproductionsummaryController', function ($scope, productionService, usSpinnerService) {
    $scope.open1 = function () { $scope.popup1.opened = true; };
    $scope.popup1 = { opened: false };
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.ProductionReportDate = new Date();
  });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 inputGroupContainer">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" ng-model="data.ProductionReportDate" is-open="popup1.opened" required close-text="Close" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `maxDate` and `minDate` in datepicker options.

According to documentation

> to configure the uib-datepicker you need to create an object in
>   Javascript with all the options and use it on the datepicker-options
>   attribute

so in your html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" ng-model="data.ProductionReportDate" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="options" required close-text="Close" />
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.options = {
      minDate: new Date(), // set this to whatever date you want to set
    }
```

Have a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QSGEniWRrmbRDNhNc74k?p=preview)

Comment: I tried but they are not working. Can you tell me with excat code how to implement?

Comment: Glad, I could help

Answer (score 2):

In `AngularJS` you can set a series of dateOptions such as dateMin, dateMax for the `uib-datepicker`

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HlD4pKJyamXGPM2UtL98?p=preview) taken from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099267/angular-ui-datepicker-in-ng-repeat-works-only-for-first-block)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with tag it self

**In controller**

```
$scope.minDate = new Date();
```

**In view**

```
 min-date="minDate" // add in uib-input
```

Just tested and Works fine

[image]